# Timetable app for myself

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, pyqt

My aim was to build a small, simple program that would show me my school timetable for the present day as well as the following day. I am new to PyQt(5) and programming in general. I started programming about 5 months ago on and off just as a fun side hobby. I started with basic text-based programs which gradually got more complex and this is my first (useful) GUI program. Any thoughts/suggestions?

```
import datetime
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap)

#My weekly school timetable
Mon = '\n1       Spanish\n2       Spanish\n3       Music\n4       Music\n5       English Literature\n6       English Literature\n7       History\n8       History'
Tue = '\n1       Social Studies\n2       Social Studies\n3       Spanish\n4       Spanish\n5       Information Technology\n6       Information Technology\n7       English Literature\n8       English Language'
Wed = '\n1       English Literature\n2       English Literature\n3       Information Technology\n4       Information Technology\n5       HSB\n6       HSB\n7       Mathematics\n8       Mathematics'
Thu = '\n1       History\n2       History\n3       English Language\n4       English Language\n5       HSB\n6       HSB\n7       Mathematics\n8       Mathematics'
Fri = '\n1       Music\n2       Music\n3       English Language\n4       English Language\n5       Mathematics\n6       Mathematics\n7       Social Studies\n8       Social Studies'

#Returns day in terms of Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1...
day = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

if day==0:
    the_day = Mon
    tomorrow = Tue
if day==1:
    the_day = Tue
    tomorrow = Wed
if day==2:
    the_day = Wed
    tomorrow = Thu
if day==3:
    the_day = Thu
    tomorrow = Fri
if day==4:
    the_day = Fri
    tomorrow = ''
elif day==5 or day==6:
    the_day = ''
    tomorrow = Mon

if day in range(5):
    today = '<b>Today\'s Timetable:<\b>'
    next_day = '<b>Tomorrow\'s Timetable:<\b>'
else:
    today = ''
    next_day = '<b>Monday\'s Timetable:<\b>'

class timetable(QWidget):               

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        if day==4:
            lbl = QLabel(self)
            pixmap = QPixmap('weekend.jpg')
            smaller_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(160, 300, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
            lbl.setPixmap(smaller_pixmap)
            lbl.move(-3, 162)
            lbl.show()

        elif day==5 or day==6:
            lbl = QLabel(self)
            pixmap = QPixmap('weekend.jpg')
            smaller_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(160, 300, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
            lbl.setPixmap(smaller_pixmap)
            lbl.move(-3, 0)
            lbl.show()            

        title0 = QLabel(today, self)
        title0.move(5,5)  

        schedule0 = QLabel(the_day, self)
        schedule0.move(5, 16)

        title1 = QLabel(next_day, self)
        title1.move(5,150)

        schedule1 = QLabel(tomorrow, self)
        schedule1.move(5, 160)

        self.setGeometry(7, 30, 150, 287)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Timetable')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = timetable()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())  
    #created with PyQt5 using Python 3.5
```

Comment: This is a code dump. Please tell us more about your specifications, what is it supposed to do and whether it lives up to your expectations.

Comment: Tough crowd. I have added additional information about the purpose of the program and my motivation to build the program. Thoughts/Suggestions for the program itself would be much appreciated.

Comment: Much better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your setup code to take a list of lists, where the inner lists are lists of subjects on that day and the outer list collects all these lists:

```
schedule = [['Spanish', 'Spanish', 'Music', 'Music', 'English Literature', 'English Literature', 'History', 'History'],
            ...]

def format_day(day_schedule):
    return "\n" + "\n".join("{}       {}".format(i, subject)
                            for i, subject in enumerate(day_schedule, 1))

today = date.datetime.today().weekday()

try:
    the_day = format_day(schedule[today])
except IndexError:
    the_day = ''
try:
    tomorrow = format_day(schedule[today + 1])
except IndexError:
    tomorrow = format_day(schedule[0])
```

This could actually be moved into the class, which could just take the `schedule` and `day` as parameters (which would make it a lot easier to run this, e.g for two different schedules):

```
import datetime
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap)


def format_day(day_schedule):
    return "\n" + "\n".join("{}       {}".format(i, subject)
                            for i, subject in enumerate(day_schedule, 1))


class Timetable(QWidget):               

    def __init__(self, schedule, day):
        super().__init__()
        self.schedule = schedule
        self.day = day
        self.init_UI()


    def init_UI(self):
        try:
            today = format_day(self.schedule[self.day])
        except IndexError:
            today = ''
        try:
            tomorrow = format_day(self.schedule[self.day + 1])
        except IndexError:
            tomorrow = format_day(self.schedule[0])

        if self.day <= 5:
            today_header = '<b>Today\'s Timetable:<\b>'
            tomorrow_header = '<b>Tomorrow\'s Timetable:<\b>'
        else:
            today_header = ''
            tomorrow_header = '<b>Monday\'s Timetable:<\b>'

        if self.day in (4, 5, 6):
            lbl = QLabel(self)
            pixmap = QPixmap('weekend.jpg')
            smaller_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(160, 300, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.FastTransformation)
            lbl.setPixmap(smaller_pixmap)
            if self.day == 4:
                lbl.move(-3, 162)
            else:
                lbl.move(-3, 0)
            lbl.show()      

        title0 = QLabel(today_header, self)
        title0.move(5, 5)
        schedule0 = QLabel(today, self)
        schedule0.move(5, 16)

        title1 = QLabel(tomorrow_header, self)
        title1.move(5, 150)
        schedule1 = QLabel(tomorrow, self)
        schedule1.move(5, 160)

        self.setGeometry(7, 30, 150, 287)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Timetable')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))      
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    schedule = [['Spanish', 'Spanish', 'Music', 'Music', 'English Literature', 'English Literature', 'History', 'History'],
                ...]
    today = date.datetime.today().weekday()
    ex = Timetable(schedule, today)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    #created with PyQt5 using Python 3.5
```

Note that I also renamed some of your variables (there is now a `today` and a `today_header` and a `tomorrow` and `tomorrow_header`.

Answer (score 2):

While @Graipher's answer is much better and more thorough, I just thought I'd point out a non-class solution to iterate through your days. If you define a list of days, you can pick variables today and tomorrow from `list_of_days[index]` and `list_of_days[index+1]` provided that you break the loop before the index reaches the last element. This way, you don't need to specify today and tomorrow for each `if` condition.